# How to retrieve any keys in dictionary of composite values by a single value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm coding a program that will print output on what is happening with parts of an internal combustion engine.  I have an abstract class called `CarSystemParts` that all car part classes inherit from.

I have a `Dictionary<CarSystemPart, List<CarSystemPart>>` that shows which classes should be affected or physically pushed by other parts.  It's defined like this:

```
        PushCycle = new Dictionary<CarSystemPart, List<CarSystemPart>>()
        {
            { Accelerator, new List<CarSystemPart> { Carburetor } },
            { AirCleaner, new List<CarSystemPart> { } },
            { Alternator, new List<CarSystemPart> { Battery } },
            { Battery, new List<CarSystemPart> {  } },
            { CamShaft, new List<CarSystemPart> { FuelPump, Distributor, ValveExhaust, ValveIntake } },
            { Carburetor, new List<CarSystemPart> { ValveIntake } },
            { Crankshaft, new List<CarSystemPart> { Alternator, TimingChain, Pistons } },
            { Distributor, new List<CarSystemPart> { SparkPlugs } },
            { Flywheel, new List<CarSystemPart> { Crankshaft } },
            { FuelPump, new List<CarSystemPart> { Carburetor } },
            { FuelTank, new List<CarSystemPart> {  } },
            { IgnitionCoil, new List<CarSystemPart> { Distributor } },
            { IgnitionSwitch, new List<CarSystemPart> { IgnitionCoil, StarterMotor } },
            { Pistons, new List<CarSystemPart> { Crankshaft } },
            { SparkPlugs, new List<CarSystemPart> { Pistons } },
            { StarterMotor, new List<CarSystemPart> { Flywheel } },
            { TimingChain, new List<CarSystemPart> { CamShaft } },
            { ValveExhaust, new List<CarSystemPart> {  } },
            { ValveIntake, new List<CarSystemPart> { Pistons } } 
        };
```

For example the Crankshaft operates the `Alternator`, `TimingChain`, and `Pistons`.

However, in several of the CarSystemPart subclasses definitions, I need to know what parts the part was affected by.

To solve this problem I want to produce a `List<CarSystemPart>` that contains each `Key` in the dictionary whose `Values` contain the `CarSystemPart` within their list.

I've seen that I can look up single values to find the key using FirstOrDefault in LINQ,

```
var key = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "ab").Key;
```

but I need each of the keys that have a value whose list contains a given part name.

Comment: `PushCycle.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(...)).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem using `Where` to filter the elements you want, then `Select` to only keep the Keys.

```
List<CarSystemPart> result = PushCycle
    .Where(e => e.Value.Contains(YourCarSystemPart)) // Filter elements that contains the CarSystemPart within their list
    .Select(e => e.Key) // Select the key of each element
    .ToList(); // Transform the IEnumerable<> into a List<>
```

Comment: I like your answer, except List<CarSystemPart> can't be set to the type Dictionary.  If I change the top line to ```var PushingParts = PushCycle``` intellisense shows no errors

Comment: Oops my mistake, indeed it should have been PushCycle.Where ...